# Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. (copy and pasting results )

Tags: excel

I am trying to put results from sheet a to different sheets accordingly.

```
Sub update()
Dim cell As String, sheet As String, rcdate As String, row As Integer
row = 2
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Auto Generate V2").Activate
cell = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Auto Generate V2").Cells(row, 10).value)
Do While cell <> ""
sheet = Left(cell, 10)
rcdate = Right(cell, 3)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet).Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet).Range(rcdate).value =                           ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Auto Generate V2").Cells(row, 5).value
row = row + 1
cell = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Auto Generate V2").Cells(row, 10).value)
Loop
End Sub
```

The error is at 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet).Range(acdate).value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Auto Generate V2").Cells(row, 5).value
How do I solve it

Comment: Try changing `row As Integer` to `row As Long`.

Comment: Tried , it pops out the same error

Comment: What is a typical value in column J of the Auto Generate V2 worksheet? Do any values get transferred or does it choke on the first one?

Comment: They are strings for location of which sheet and which cell ,  5 values get transferred and after that it choke.

Comment: I solved it , thanks jeeped . Instead of combining two values in a cell for location , i should have split them up

Answer (score 0):

The unnecessary [Worksheet.Activate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838003.aspx) are no doubt contributing to an unstable environment. I've modified your routine to remove dependence on the .ActiveSheet.

```
Sub update()
    Dim cell As String, sht As String, rcDate As String, rw As Long
    rw = 2
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Auto Generate V2")
        cell = Trim(CStr(.Cells(rw, 10).Value))
        Do While cell <> ""
            sht = Left(cell, 10)
            rcDate = Right(cell, 3)
            'Debug.Print .Parent.Worksheets(sht).Range(rcDate).Address(external:=True)
            .Parent.Worksheets(sht).Range(rcDate) = .Cells(rw, 5).Value
            rw = rw + 1
            cell = Trim(CStr(.Cells(rw, 10).Value))
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

If you are still having trouble, consider closing everything off and rebooting the computer. A series of crashes made during the development of a sub can lead to an underlying unstable compiler environment. More than once a simple machine restart has fixed an unknown problem.